# Which of the following is more pythonic?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

One of the examples I'm using on the excellent Tkdocs site, is talking about check boxes and I wanted to modify it to show me which check boxes were checked (in a label).

I defined a function, and then re-did it thinking the second is clearer and 
therefore more pythonic.

However I'm sure there is a better way still...

If its not obvious onevar twovar and threevar are the checkboxes, outvar is the variable which I'm displaying in my label...

Comments welcome!

```
    def checkvars(*args):
        if onevar.get():
            if twovar.get():
                if threevar.get():
                    outvar.set('All three are true')
                else:
                    outvar.set('one and two are set to true')
            elif threevar.get():
                outvar.set('one and three are set to true')
            else:
                outvar.set('one is set to true')
        elif twovar.get():
            if threevar.get():
                outvar.set('two and three are set to true')
            else:
                outvar.set('two is set to true')
        elif threevar.get():
            outvar.set('three is set to true')
        else:
            outvar.set('They are all false')

    def checkvars2(*args):
        if onevar.get() and twovar.get() and threevar.get():
            outvar.set('All three are true')
        elif onevar.get() and twovar.get():
            outvar.set('one and two are set to true')
        elif onevar.get() and threevar.get():
            outvar.set('one and three are set to true')
        elif onevar.get():
            outvar.set('one is set to true')
        elif twovar.get() and threevar.get():
            outvar.set('two and three are set to true')
        elif twovar.get():
            outvar.set('two is set to true')
        elif threevar.get():
            outvar.set('three is set to true')
        else:
            outvar.set('They are all false')
```

Comment: This should perhaps been posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I think the term you were looking for is 'pythonic'. A Pythonista is a (not very commonly used) term for someone who codes in Python.

Comment: Neither does look really good because of the code duplication. I'd get the checkbox values once and perhaps used that tuple as a dict key to get the message.

Comment: I'm not sure being python makes any difference here -- any language with "if" and "else" will have this problem :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small variation on azorius answer for completeness:

```
def checkvars(*args):
    flags = [x.get() for x in (onevar, twovar, threevar)]

    # Generate a list containing the corresponding string representation of
    # each checked flag value.
    # For example: (True, False, True) gives ('one', 'three')
    num_strings = ('one', 'two', 'three')
    val_strings = [s for f, s in zip(flags, num_strings) if f]

    # Number of checked values correspond to the number of strings.
    checked_count = len(val_strings)
    if checked_count == 0:
        outvar.set('They are all false')
    elif checked_count == len(flags):
        outvar.set('All three are true')
    else:
        verb = 'is' if len(val_strings) == 1 else 'are'
        outvar.set('%s %s set to true' % (' and '.join(val_strings), verb))
```

Regardless of the language, a function with that many `if` / `elif` is rarely acceptable.

Comment: Fairplay, Didn't think it was the best way to do it, not actually seen the zip function before, and the whole val_strings line will need a bit more research... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

how about something along the lines of:
this is not much shorter than what you have, but if you get just a few more 'vars' then this scales a lot better

```
def checkvars(*args):
    numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    flags = [x.get() for x in (onevar, twovar, threevar)]
    numbers = filter(flags, numbers)
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        outvar.set('They are all false')
    elif len(numbers) == len(numbers):
        outvar.set('All three are true')
    else:
        is_are = {1 : 'is'}.get(l, 'are')
        comma_list = ''.join(('%s, ' % x for x in numbers[:-2]))
        and_list = ' and '.join(numbers[-2:])
        outvar.set(%s%s %s set to true' % (comma_list, and_list, is_are))
```

changed the last else to ', ' separate when there are 3 or more in numbers

Comment: It just needs a little test to print `is` when `len(numbers) == 1` :)

Comment: I taught I was so smart because ' and '.join(['one']) prints 'one'... stupid gamma destroying everything!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Azorius, Again, not yet seen the filter function...Appreciate your effort!